# What PHP IDE's have outside of file Syntax Highlighter's?

Tags: php, drupal, ide, joomla, content-management-system

I am not looking for a debate on best, I just want to know what PHP IDE's have features for highlighting classes, functions and any other relationships **outside of the viewed page**, to save time on scrolling through pages of code. I would be accessing MVC like frameworks and want this to extend off of my existing page, so covering the actual project.

I have a handful of IDE's I am playing with, but yet to find something that extends to full project as well as I would like. Or maybe I have not used these to their full potential. Any thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated. I also have looked for IDE's recently to help with CMS projects, but that is a whole other story and would likely create a debate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use [PHP Storm 3](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/).

But there are some other IDEs like [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) or [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt)

Comment: And this has good highlighting for what I am looking for? Regardless, I have seen some good reviews on PHP Storm in my recent search.

Comment: I had some IDEs in the past and i find for myself that PHP Storm 3 is the best of them. There are a lot of highlightings inside you don't need to install extensions for the most things like TWIG or LESS or something else.

Comment: I am really liking PHP Storm. So far it looks to cover a lot of my needs without any extensions installed.

Comment: I think the problem with other IDEs is that more and more extensions and the IDE will be slower and slower this is why i've tried Aptana and then PHP Storm.

Comment: I have decided to run with PHP Storm for a bit as my primary for now, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

We use Eclipse Classic http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ with the PDT extension http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt, you can add anything you need, as SVN, CVS, web tools (javascript, HTML, CSS, ...)

You can install PDT and anything else from the 'software install' inside Eclipse.

Comment: I have made good use of Eclipse for many projects outside of PHP, but ran into a few issues setting up for PHP. Maybe it is time to sort through my options again as there are some really good things about Eclipse I like, including all the extensions.

Comment: Installing PHP/Aptana extensions was very painful. Now they completely changed their approach, and installing PHP Classic, then PDT is very straight-forward. I use the same Eclipse installation for C++, Java and PHP projects, and I'm very happy about it.

Answer (score 3):

Another vote for PHPStorm.

But due to PHP's dynamic nature, there are lots of scenarios where the IDE cannot figure out what is going on without explicit help, no matter which IDE you choose.

For example, if your code looks like `AbstractService::getInstance($service_class_name)`, the IDE cannot know the actual type of the returned object unless you annotate it using PHPDoc *or* it has specifically implemented support for such a pattern. In my experience, most PHP frameworks use strings like that a lot.

Comment: One of the projects I really need this for is a Joomla site, this scenario seems to apply unfortunately. It would be nice to have this conquered. It looks as though CodeLobster is attempting to solve some of these issues in CMS at least, but I have yet to see it work the way I would like.